# Move to directory that was no directory

Tags: mv

I did this:

```
mv couchpotato_11-08-2016_09-35.tar.gz ~/AtoMiC-ToolKit/backup
mv transmission-daemon_11-08-2016_09-36.tar.gz ~/AtoMiC-ToolKit/backup
mv sickrage_11-08-2016_09-35.tar.gz ~/AtoMiC-ToolKit/backup
```

But `backup` was no directory or file, and now the files are gone.

How do I find or restore these files?

Comment: The answers below are unfortunately correct in their assertions that you have overwritten the first two files with the third, when you mistakenly `mv`'d them to become the file named `backup`. It may be possible to get the files back with a recovery utility like testdisk. To avoid this in the future, it can be useful to input the trailing `/` when you want to move something into a directory, `mv` will issue a warning that the directory doesn't exist.

Comment: You might want to `alias mv='mv -i'`, and get into the habit of using trailing slashes in `mv foo /bar/` (as opposed to `mv foo /bar`).

Answer (score 7):

Your files are gone and only your last file 'sickrage_11-08-2016_09-35.tar.gz ' is still there and renamed to 'backup' in '~/AtoMiC-ToolKit/'

To restoring it back just run (assuming you didn't change your working directory yet)

```
mv ~/AtoMiC-ToolKit/backup $PWD/sickrage_11-08-2016_09-35.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 2):

If backup didn't exist as a directory, a file will be created with that name. Then your second and third `mv` command would overwrite the previous. You won't be able to retreive the previous files.

Answer (score 2):

When no destination folder exists, `mv` **doesn't move** the file rather **renames** it. Had you used it just once you could have recovered the file, but you used it thrice so **first and second file got overwritten by the third file**

So basically **sickrage_11-08-2016_09-35.tar.gz** is now **~/AtoMiC-ToolKit/backup**. If it doesnt show up, turn the "Show Hidden Files" option on to see it.